# Linking <option> with onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I am building my own shopping website, and I got stuck in this part:

```html
<label for="option">Option</label>
<select id="option">
    <optgroup>
        <option onclick="changeValueA()">Option A</option>
        <option onclick="changeValueB()">Option B</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>

<p>You choosed Option <span id="option-value"></span></p>

<script>
    
    function changeValueA(){
        
       document.getElementById("option-value").innerHTML = "Option A";

    }

    function changeValueB(){
        
       document.getElementById("option-value").innerHTML = "Option B";

    }

</script>
```

I want to make "option-value" display "Option A" if changeValueA() is called by clicking the Option A from <select>, and I want to make "option-value" display "Option B" if changeValueB() is called by clicking the Option B from <select>.

However, the code doesn't work. It would be really grateful if you help me this part!

Comment: The `click` event does not work on `<option>`s cross-browser.

Comment: it don't work like that you have to take value from `select`

Comment: Use `document.getElementById("option").addEventListener("change", ({ target: { selectedOptions: [ { textContent: option } ] } }) => document.getElementById("option-value").innerHTML = option);` instead. Don’t forget to remove your `onclick` attributes.

Answer (score 3):

`option` elements don't respond to click events (as you can see by the added `console.log`s below); you instead need to check the `<select>`'s value:

```js
// these functions never run:
function changeValueA() {
  console.log("A") 
  document.getElementById("option-value").innerHTML = "Option A";
}

function changeValueB() {
  console.log("B")
  document.getElementById("option-value").innerHTML = "Option B";
}

// This one will be triggered by the select's onchange handler,
// and passes the selected value in so you don't need multiple 
// similar functions:
function changeValue(val) {
  document.getElementById("option-value").innerHTML = val;
}
```

```html
<label for="option">Option</label>
<select id="option" onchange="changeValue(this.value)">
  <optgroup>
    <option onclick="changeValueA()">Option A</option>
    <option onclick="changeValueB()">Option B</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>

<p>You chose <span id="option-value"></span></p>
```